# pod with app is getting evicted from gke as out of memory even if there is only 1/3rd memory used

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am newbie to gke.

I have python app running inside a gke pod. Pod gets evicted as out of memory after 30minutes. Total vm memory is 13GB, and as i ssh into the pod, the peak used memory before eviction is only about 3GB...

I have tried running some dummy code as defined in Dockerfile `"CMD tail -f /dev/null"`, then connect to the pod and running scraper script manually, with success - being able to finish with peak mem usage of 9 GB.

docker file:

```
CMD python3 scraper.py

> Managed pods Revision Name    Status  Restarts    Created on 1
>   scraper-df68b65bf-gbhms      Running    0   Sep 2, 2019, 2:59:59 PM 1
>   scraper-df68b65bf-gktqw      Running    0   Sep 2, 2019, 2:59:59 PM 1
>   scraper-df68b65bf-z4kjb      Running    0   Sep 2, 2019, 2:59:59 PM 1
>   scraper-df68b65bf-wk6td      Running    0   Sep 2, 2019, 3:00:45 PM 1
>   scraper-df68b65bf-xqm7h      Running    0   Sep 2, 2019, 3:00:45 PM
```

My guess is there are many instances of my app running inside of space of 13 GB in many parallel pods?  How do I run single instance of my app on gke so I have all memory from vm available to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have replica count set to one in your deployment.yaml file?

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
```

In case it is HorizontalPodAutoscaler you can edit it by:

1. Get the HorizontalPodAutoscaler

   `kubectl get HorizontalPodAutoscaler`
2. Edit it by using the edit command

   `kubectl edit HorizontalPodAutoscaler <pod scaler name>`

And the end result of HorizontalPodAutoscaler looks like this

```
spec:
  maxReplicas: 1
  minReplicas: 1
```

Comment: i think i have autoscaler. I created cluster in gke from website then in workload tabs added my container. the only option i see here is to view yaml file.   `minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 5` how do I edit it?

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!! I suppose i was expecting it could be scheduled from web ui. So, its best to forget google gke webui and run everything with command line?

Comment: Command line give to more control mainly in editing various kubernetes objects.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome reply @Bismal.

@Wotjas, just to add my 2 cents; you can use the Cloud Console to set the min and max values, you just need to go to:
Cloud Menu -> GKE -> Workloads -> Actions -> Scale

Set the desired values, then save.
More detailed information can be found in this document [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/scaling-apps